# More information popup on Wordpress Php function

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a popup.

The *more info* popup should show up when I click on a `(?)` icon.

Currently, clicking the `(?)` font awesome icon shows "no content found" message.

I have no idea of what is going wrong, I use a lightbox class in the following code:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3 );

function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name, $product ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$name;
    if( $taxonomy == 'pa_color' )
        $label .= '
          <div class="bs-example">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div id="popup">
                <a href="#" class="lightbox" title="BLABLABLA"
                ><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
              </div>';
    return $label;
}
```

Can somebody help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason your code does not contain the closing `</div>` tag for `.bs-example` and `.wrapper`? There isn't any content in your code, where does the lightbox get the "more info" content?

Comment: I think the structure code is wrong. Your right I did not saw that. How to refer the lightbox with the content? I thought that the lightbox refers the title tag.